# Can I add a second SSD to my laptop, to keep other operating systems

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive

I have a laptop with 128GB SSD storage. I don't keep a lot of files, but I do need to install at least 2 different OS (Windows and Linux Mint), and install some software that take up certain amounts of space. Also, ideally I would like to play around with other OS. So 128 GB are not enough for me.

I decided to buy a new SSD of 256GB. Now I am wondering if I can still use the current SSD to keep one of the OS, for example Windows. I would use windows occasionally anyway, but once in a while I really need it.

So, can I keep the current SSD as an external drive, with a fully functioning windows OS? If yes, are there any risks to it? I am not referring to risk of data loss, because that is obviously something I have to always keep in mind regardless of OS or disk type. I was more wondering about things such as hardware damage or bad performance.

Comment: How will you connect it?  USB2 is much slower than USB3 and would be painful to use.  You may also want to consider a cable/enclosure that supports [UASP](https://blog.startech.com/post/all-you-need-to-know-about-uasp/) so trim works - like [this](https://www.startech.com/HDD/Adapters/usb-3-1-gen-2-sata-adapter-cable~USB312SAT3CB) for example.

Comment: @lx07 this is kinda the feedback I wanted. I know nothing about hardware, never done this before, and I have no idea what the possible issues could be

Comment: I use a virtual machine on a 512GB SSD through USB3 running Windows and I haven't had any issues with it. You can periodically back up a snapshot of the VM to a different location (but be warned, it takes up a good amount of space). Might be an option.